# How to plot Error Bars in a 3D scatter plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

This is a simple problem which is proving difficult to solve. I want to plot error bars on points in a 3D scatter graph. I plot error bars on points within a 2D scatter by:

```
ErrorListPlot[{{{x1_,y1_},ErrorBar[x1_err,y1_err]},{x2_,y2_},ErrorBar[x2err_,y2err_]}}]
```

I can plot 3D point data by:

```
ListPointPlot3D[{{x1_,y1_,z1_},{x2_,y2_,z2_}}]
```

However, the `ErrorBar` function doesn't seem to work in 3D (have tried `ErrorBar3D` and variations of).

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mathematica.SE. When you write a post, you can use many things like code-blocks, links, section titles, etc. Please look through the [documention here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to see how you use it. More important, please read [our FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/faq) to understand how voting, asking good questions and all this works.

Comment: Do you want bars or ellipsoids?

Comment: Be sure to check out the variety of visualization functions in Mathematica, beyond ListPointPlot: http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/statistical-visualization/

Answer (score 31):

In my opinion 3D data plots are very, very confusing and you need to provide the user a multitude of visual cues to improve his/her interpretation. As a first draft I'd suggest something like:

```
t[x_, y_, z_, dx_, dy_, dz_] := 
  GeometricTransformation[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], 
   AffineTransform[{DiagonalMatrix[{dx, dy, dz}], {x, y, z}}]];

data = {{10, 10, 10, 2, 2, 2}, {20, 25, 20, 2, 2, 4}, {20, 10, 30, 4, 2, 1}, 
        {20, 30, 40, 1, 2, 3}, {30, 30, 30, 2, 1, 1}};
Graphics3D[{Line[{{#1, #2, 0}, {#1, #2, #3}}], Red, 
    Tube[{{#1 - #4, #2, #3}, {#1 + #4, #2, #3}}], 
    Tube[{{#1, #2 - #5, #3}, {#1, #2 + #5, #3}}], 
    Tube[{{#1, #2, #3 - #6}, {#1, #2, #3 + #6}}], {Blue, 
     PointSize[0.04], Point[{#1, #2, #3}]}, {Opacity[0.4], 
     t[#1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6]}} & @@@ data, Axes -> True, 
 FaceGrids -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare that to this one:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which would you use?

Answer (score 29):

Yet another way:

[image]

In this plot, data points are represented in a 3D space, whereas errors are represented on the (x,y), (x,z), and (y,z) planes as textures using `ErrorListPlot`.

Here the code:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

data = {{.5, .5, .5, .2, .2, .2}, {-.4, -.1, .2, .2, .2, .3}, {.2, \
.1, .3, .1, .2, .1}, {-.2, .3, .4, .1, .2, .3}, {.3, -.3, -.3, .2, \
.1, .1}};

xyzSpace = Graphics3D[{
      {Lighter[Green], Sphere[{#1, #2, #3}, .03]},
      {Dashed, Black, Thickness[.003], 
       Line[{{#1, #2, -1}, {#1, #2, #3}}]},
      {Dashed, Black, Thickness[.003], 
       Line[{{#1, 1, #3}, {#1, #2, #3}}]},
      {Dashed, Black, Thickness[.003], 
       Line[{{-1, #2, #3}, {#1, #2, #3}}]}
      } & @@@ data, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
   BoxRatios -> 1, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}];

xyPlane = 
  ErrorListPlot[
   {{#1, #2}, ErrorBar[#4, #5]} & @@@ data, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> {Darker[Green], Thickness[.01], PointSize[.03]}, 
   ImageSize -> 400];

xzPlane = 
  ErrorListPlot[
   {{#1, #3}, ErrorBar[#4, #6]} & @@@ data, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> {Darker[Green], Thickness[.01], PointSize[.03]}, 
   ImageSize -> 800];

yzPlane = 
  ErrorListPlot[
   {{#2, #3}, ErrorBar[#5, #6]} & @@@ data, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> {Darker[Green], Thickness[.01], PointSize[.03]}, 
   ImageSize -> 800];

xyTex = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], {Texture[xyPlane], 
     Polygon[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}}, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}},
    Boxed -> False];

xzTex = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], {Texture[xzPlane], 
     Polygon[{{-1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}}, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}},
    Boxed -> False];

yzTex = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], {Texture[yzPlane], 
     Polygon[{{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {-1, -1, 1}}, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}},
    Boxed -> False];

Show[xyzSpace, xyTex, xzTex, yzTex, Axes -> True, 
 Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, {2, -3, 4}}}, ImageSize -> 800]
```

Comment: Very nice solution +1

Comment: Wow! The things that can be done.  Very nice, indeed.

Comment: @Edmund How would you adapt this to be suitable for more recent version of Mathematica? I think ErrorBar is obsolete now. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnDoe Intriguingly enough, if you see a black cube, the problem is related to the lighting direction! change `Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, {0, 0, 0}}}` to `Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, {2, -3, 4}}}` or something similar and it should work!

Comment: Modified a working directional light in the answer.

Answer (score 14):

Another way:

```
data = RandomInteger[{3, 7}, {5, 3}];
ErrorBar3D[point_, error_] := {Blue, 
  Scale[Sphere[point], RandomReal[{.1, .3}, 3], point], Dashed, 
  Line /@ Partition[ Riffle[(# + point) & /@ (IdentityMatrix[3] ( 
                           rs[[All, 1]] - point)), {point}, {2, -1, 2}], 2]}
rs = ({Min@# - 1, Max@# + 1} & /@ Transpose@data);
Show[{Graphics3D[ErrorBar3D[#, RandomReal[{.1, .4}]] & /@ data], 
      ContourPlot3D[{x == rs[[1, 1]], y == rs[[2, 1]], z == rs[[3, 1]]}, 
                     Evaluate[Sequence @@ (({{x, Sequence @@ #[[1]]}, 
                                             {y, Sequence @@ #[[2]]}, 
                                             {z, Sequence @@ #[[3]]}}) &@rs)], 
       Mesh -> None, 
       ContourStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.3], Specularity[White, 30]]]}, 
       Boxed -> True, PlotRange -> rs, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't look like there's a built-in way to do it. Here's a custom approach:

```
data = {{1, 4, 2}, {2, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 3}, {3, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 1}};
ErrorBar3D[point_, error_] := 
  Line[{point - {0, 0, error}, point + {0, 0, error}}];

Show[{
  ListPointPlot3D[data],
  Graphics3D[ErrorBar3D[#, RandomReal[{.1, .4}]] & /@ data]
  }, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Output showing ErrorBar3D]

Comment: Hmmm, without drop-down shadows you don't have a clue about the points' locations. Could be anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Using built-in functions:

```
data = Around @@@ Transpose[Partition[#, 3, 3]] & /@ 
 {{10, 10, 10, 2, 2, 2}, {20, 25, 20, 2, 2, 4}, {20, 10, 30, 4, 2, 1}, {20, 30, 40, 1, 2, 3}, {30, 30, 30, 2, 1, 1}};

ListPointPlot3D[data, IntervalMarkers -> "Tubes", PlotRange -> All, 
                Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness[0.005]]]
```

[image: graph]