# 3D plot of a dataset

Tags: plotting

I have this dataset

```
dataset1 = {{0, 10, 1.8988}, {0.234, 10, 1.546}, {0.5, 10, 
           1.98765}, {0.89, 10, 2.12377}, {1.01, 10, 2.345}, {1.345, 10, 
           2.789}, {1.908, 10, 3.123}};
 dataset2={{0.12, 8, 0.3456}, {0.16, 8, 0.567}, {0.22, 8, 0.8765}, {0.367, 8, 0.9877}, {0.9876, 8, 1.234}, {1.6889, 8, 1.7889}, {1, 87655, 8, 2.123}};
 dataset3={{0.267, 10, 2.56}, {0.6778, 10, 3.098}, {0.945, 10, 4.89}, {1.345, 10, 5.123}, {1.987, 10, 5.987}, {2.345, 10, 5.899}, {3.123, 10, 7.345}}; 
dataset4={{0.456, 13, 3.123}, {0.7643, 13, 4.1234}, {1.788, 13, 5.654}, {2.122, 13, 6.123}, {3.123, 13, 6.98}, {4.123, 13, 7.123}, {5.123, 13, 8.123}};
```

and I wrote this code to display it.

```
ListPointPlot3D[{dataset}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
  Axes -> True, 
  Ticks -> {{0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5}, {14}, {0.9, 2, 2.7}}, 
  ClipPlanesStyle -> {Opacity[6, Gray]}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Concentration", "Carbon atoms", "Dipole moment"}, 
  ImageSize -> 500, 
  FaceGrids -> None, 
  ViewPoint -> {1.5, 14, 3}, 
  FillingStyle -> LightBlue, 
  Boxed -> True , 
  BoxStyle -> {Hue[0.54, 0.46, 0.89], Thickness[0.003]}, 
  BaseStyle -> Gray, 
  AxesStyle -> Thick]
```

The code does not give a proper 3D plot.

I want to construct a 3D plot like [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85717/3066), but I was unable to do it.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange! I'm not sure what you mean by a "proper 3D plot". Your code results in a 3D plot just fine for me - perhaps you could elaborate, and maybe include details on what you would expect to see vs what you're seeing.

Comment: You are almost there. Just remove the curly braces around the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you have data for nuclides other than ${}^{10}C$, then using `ListPointPlot3D` makes sense and  Alexei Boulbitch's suggestion will make your data points show up. However, I would suggest some further changes to your code. I would rewrite like this:

```
ListPointPlot3D[dataset,
  PlotStyle -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[8]},
  Ticks -> {{0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5}, {14}, {0.9, 2, 2.7}}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Concentration", "Carbon nuclide", "Dipole moment"}, 
  ImageSize -> 500,
  ViewPoint -> {1.5, 14, 3},
  Filling -> Axis,
  FillingStyle -> Lighter[Blue, .6],
  Boxed -> True,
  BoxStyle -> {Hue[0.54, 0.46, 0.89], Thickness[0.003]},
  BaseStyle -> Gray,
  AxesStyle -> Thick]
```

which gives

[image: 3Dplot]

I've removed some options that were not needed and added the option `Filling -> Axis` which ***is*** needed.

However, if  ${}^{10}C$ is only nuclide you have data for, it would better to make a 2D plot. Like so:

```
ListPlot[dataset[[All, {1, 3}]],
  PlotStyle -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[8]},
  Ticks -> {{0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5}, {0.9, 2, 2.7}},
  PlotLabel -> Row[{Superscript["", 10], "C"}],
  AxesLabel -> {"Concentration", "Dipole moment"},
  ImageSize -> 500,
  Filling -> Axis,
  FillingStyle -> Lighter[Blue, .6],
  BaseStyle -> Gray]
```

[image: 2Dplot]

Comment: I want to construct a 3D plot like this. with three varying axis. But I was unable to construct this..https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85717/mathematica-3d-plot-based-on-combined-2d-graphs.

Comment: @S.Pyne. But the data sample you show doesn't support making such a plot. Please edit your question so as to give us a better sample of your data.

Comment: I have attached three set of datapoint here.dataset1={{0.12, 8, 0.3456}, {0.16, 8, 0.567}, {0.22, 8, 0.8765}, {0.367, 8, 
      0.9877}, {0.9876, 8, 1.234}, {1.6889, 8, 1.7889}, {1, 87655, 8, 
      2.123}};
    dataset2={{0.267, 10, 2.56}, {0.6778, 10, 3.098}, {0.945, 10, 4.89}, {1.345, 
      10, 5.123}, {1.987, 10, 5.987}, {2.345, 10, 5.899}, {3.123, 10, 
      7.345}};
    dataset3={{0.456, 13, 3.123}, {0.7643, 13, 4.1234}, {1.788, 13, 5.654}, {2.122,
       13, 6.123}, {3.123, 13, 6.98}, {4.123, 13, 7.123}, {5.123, 13, 
      8.123}};

Comment: @S.Pyne. Posting the additional data in a comment to my answer is totally inappropriate. Please **edit** your question so it includes this additional data.