# 3D Timeline of 2D Barcharts

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, charts

This post may be related to this one : [3D plot based on combined 2D graphs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85717/mathematica-3d-plot-based-on-combined-2d-graphs)

Consider the following (big) dataset which represents some results at time t=1 :

```
DataT1 = {{0.24267529829201542`, 0.20068161502014795`, 0.14473526450753776`, 0.09571298753884822`, 0.05635036266109927`, 0.04075962956296062`, 0.027508649639363003`, 0.02023858828234283`, 0.014805112839688103`, 0.010323626381156767`, 0.006793734006882825`, 0.004487357287159168`, 0.003076609386861136`, 0.0020877531489814443`, 0.0014651524174817102`, 0.0009904523212830591`, 0.0006626153203382617`, 0.0004299331563424934`, 0.00026442410887441776`, 0.00015778124670635935`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.000010601577807799415`, 0.000010686999216667553`, 0.`, 8.65157823406588`*^-8, 9.960125476678511`*^-7, 8.876651238580664`*^-6, 7.73035296874366`*^-6, 0.000019229470670477465`, 0.00001073172514458768`, 0.`, 0.00001593740588147041`, 0.000016852664246118735`, 0.00010881717931633855`, 0.00012176402559894376`, 0.00013610710333904894`}, {0.0022759056073056376`, 0.00047929008528391974`, 0.0019620697275647228`, 0.0012417891913117454`, 0.0007801068584611102`, 0.0006797726196230614`, 0.0006139118846098434`, 0.00036889785496836117`, 0.00030388449252859807`, 0.00017661324749453623`, 0.0002312630168661034`, 0.0002451263493936626`, 0.00021624937571952226`, 0.0001847868059908665`, 0.00015223373020703502`, 0.00013661310899566032`, 0.00012665766949817046`, 0.00011557444545636082`, 0.00006825212060816093`, 0.00006387913224960545`, 0.00007465495735965976`, 0.00006322091971213316`, 0.000060610404527156866`, 0.00009370058216631413`, 0.00009121543484416458`, 0.00009078824945370666`, 0.0001020345510564568`, 0.0001228304211051307`, 0.0001126697948261544`, 0.0001193990362469232`, 0.00011887726061433906`, 0.00008549893020116805`, 0.00010576886059011898`, 0.0000996805452621829`, 0.0001327651709206245`, 0.00009813420012544872`, 0.00009716943960948756`, 0.00009801650588647693`, 0.00010155216699708072`, 0.00006604941084074835`, 0.00008034365061069933`, 0.0001923200649199543`, 0.0002885856878809037`, 0.00031422270661612283`, 0.0003303345935638699`, 0.00033889594902693844`, 0.00034707088645378293`, 0.00037038754378468803`, 0.0003939093497023748`}, {0.12207084002621861`, 0.10244860739115967`, 0.07262941421856464`, 0.05006830050814784`, 0.03126727422820718`, 0.02251031211377001`, 0.017387973891337814`, 0.01263312315360195`, 0.009658867730013843`, 0.007716006227411685`, 0.005923500210634978`, 0.004529582521627972`, 0.0036015636201765047`, 0.0028108821947924263`, 0.0021400114537507646`, 0.0017047647726279598`, 0.0013712246523433242`, 0.0010811335140092782`, 0.000925712204658619`, 0.0007195885721322248`, 0.0005294524649297499`, 0.00046069626565996426`, 0.00037765837922061087`, 0.00028329782825221584`, 0.00022978127909699373`, 0.0001863318776941183`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.00007490395655006032`, 0.00008651658002664281`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.00009138256932939893`, 0.0000637633471968183`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.01014736720834639`, 0.01176986042699429`, 0.006298824119348238`, 0.003022266455440099`, 0.0026764570333815104`, 0.0010601020776922533`, 0.0006394347054632207`, 0.000505704283664161`, 0.00034193667858141603`, 0.00019065823608909648`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.00003435018688937396`, 0.000025909932188259918`, 0.000012317433841677905`, 0.000010275468891622851`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.09080992584523617`, 0.13252869258555894`, 0.15989562196919188`, 0.16242819765561417`, 0.15331433568158287`, 0.1456083660655398`, 0.14083581421053523`, 0.13647700616302055`, 0.13180314900744533`, 0.1256696832695108`, 0.12225821150763744`, 0.12259290670327107`, 0.11811105088124826`, 0.11330401830954775`, 0.1083621442439352`, 0.10373588238756778`, 0.09917723627042001`, 0.0944303568018536`, 0.08936644410288148`, 0.08426532771357703`, 0.07887384881828438`, 0.07336432851897708`, 0.06820093899680571`, 0.06418421391641732`, 0.05916071388907184`, 0.05427889976325328`, 0.049011436445523755`, 0.04401019632087219`, 0.03893112045224106`, 0.03463940714075084`, 0.03064994173766554`, 0.02632473196493445`, 0.023598822325438872`, 0.02095079443947157`, 0.018252594933771772`, 0.016266119633070678`, 0.015435599130945919`, 0.013443513610005401`, 0.01226289680973176`, 0.011056176018432347`, 0.009903793610336921`, 0.008435031080664346`, 0.007796487969740817`, 0.00741070609404624`, 0.006913856554946287`, 0.006335545670067945`, 0.006116249210592028`, 0.005985150810137377`, 0.005968865625154404`}, {3.7973988178178947`*^-7, 0.0014168329405636272`, 0.0021974889608878685`, 0.0023136556850808596`, 0.0034547921206025123`, 0.0023999743424502795`, 0.0023979530930042475`, 0.0021884615589332175`, 0.0021047490246144797`, 0.002148341362399503`, 0.00188447682925446`, 0.001461587875281016`, 0.0014245135605613123`, 0.0013711499317578266`, 0.0012753921251628772`, 0.0011879245588058678`, 0.0011102198309408352`, 0.0010361279504539735`, 0.0010352831334954698`, 0.0009534728349914322`, 0.0008472425702207839`, 0.0008091438645046222`, 0.0007559165946144882`, 0.0008643063071157536`, 0.0008036358744660276`, 0.0007476147381350257`, 0.000608077192636141`, 0.0005636738253471477`, 0.0005536478363904412`, 0.0005154922064448609`, 0.0005880797535676285`, 0.0003392483594555051`, 0.00033120120603467526`, 0.00033864661852507427`, 0.00024850482243969716`, 0.00021058593852215645`, 0.000025916887582162753`, 0.000016452422732566875`, 0.000014646524353694852`, 5.462329840748853`*^-6, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.007358919025640691`, 0.05719574391389733`, 0.15968827361869037`, 0.2507544218515287`, 0.32934461141595667`, 0.3683005047069475`, 0.39393546132452634`, 0.41377724224143336`, 0.4287936099246521`, 0.44379697958742054`, 0.4562609372913472`, 0.45909656423016104`, 0.4680580172078559`, 0.47509568510726335`, 0.48106064845097446`, 0.48540901434575745`, 0.4888072506397643`, 0.4914412424721872`, 0.493824859873668`, 0.4956327595845475`, 0.500252591072978`, 0.5017356393708713`, 0.5032040032699913`, 0.5036157556877244`, 0.5055298358417791`, 0.5076064765065712`, 0.5129797591279771`, 0.5153785173303004`, 0.5172313088017613`, 0.5192560489407236`, 0.5212495502452326`, 0.5243269372201123`, 0.5262058419713903`, 0.5266010882790989`, 0.5275199427493171`, 0.5271857696911629`, 0.5267686186940466`, 0.5263106325259777`, 0.5246385370605173`, 0.5209487611640661`, 0.5180853069892567`, 0.517092272050771`, 0.5059793795638915`, 0.4977843958617724`, 0.48564438897704104`, 0.46965714456756424`, 0.4461490677799926`, 0.4168744608793916`, 0.3786265363128056`}, {0.0321087660149724`, 0.01127144583084005`, 0.03492975574694252`, 0.0706706284739759`, 0.11269702723463505`, 0.13466572364479723`, 0.14944107916449798`, 0.16193517239984026`, 0.1703892940922775`, 0.1749362371972154`, 0.18077668834621938`, 0.1868009144886233`, 0.19101158919402955`, 0.1954608587183838`, 0.19916737911130308`, 0.20358504401959246`, 0.20834935392921558`, 0.2136672153580344`, 0.22081266097817695`, 0.22699492376271563`, 0.2333958789200174`, 0.24030229377464982`, 0.24658294436174366`, 0.252526079670778`, 0.25834467122497823`, 0.26391178938101567`, 0.2687455013313043`, 0.27433484710087624`, 0.2816287470143833`, 0.2866112232847427`, 0.29128996374109173`, 0.2955548014592611`, 0.29743176340874516`, 0.3013020975860231`, 0.30604477782139883`, 0.31056919353081075`, 0.3093242589712076`, 0.31113379895866133`, 0.31141172125845934`, 0.31332382910757667`, 0.31272533042454376`, 0.30620109979944143`, 0.3040916774363062`, 0.2985104081533787`, 0.2909930007519726`, 0.2816736812441758`, 0.2673852958342979`, 0.24884942843482546`, 0.2253268720378219`}, {0.0002310608452322154`, 0.000042903792302095004`, 0.000290956642502981`, 0.00004891357553756302`, 0.0007523785698467965`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.00007877990795237225`, 0.00011545600196271442`, 0.`, 0.000160322027596338`, 0.00021203834101464827`, 0.0002662347064716854`, 0.0003340371916544916`, 0.0004451294534921893`, 0.0005605228020148421`, 0.0007048139889902512`}, {0.0030386603252494228`, 0.0036717946718898132`, 0.0017648413482621115`, 0.0016445998657451705`, 0.00041302491809167073`, 0.0009443544602861295`, 0.0007062132977428844`, 0.000640199908295414`, 0.0004806902886880057`, 0.0004177169801752555`, 0.0004273107887021631`, 0.00029568841291498975`, 0.00025803628337723564`, 0.0002230329005153187`, 0.00023207133737199252`, 0.0002166361642090932`, 0.00020459610203061042`, 0.0001968083430453321`, 0.0001307051042607044`, 0.00013060194594487787`, 0.000109158572910608`, 0.00006674705381212056`, 0.00006563105339011225`, 0.00006584756954198104`, 0.00006404531002974991`, 0.00006180634398028608`, 0.00009300174420221063`, 0.00008667479205671328`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.00006526265047953064`, 0.00004990115551344223`, 0.00008514550920658797`, 0.00002619370961269547`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.000035000135740858465`, 0.000034815734432023645`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.4025641109845738`, 0.37640348250732436`, 0.2880339236400904`, 0.21460398170529404`, 0.14297511842772628`, 0.11430977957368905`, 0.09122183219470618`, 0.07524764011881255`, 0.06320120882507371`, 0.0535569576449738`, 0.04385780036926442`, 0.03757098329487827`, 0.03288554762980924`, 0.029304401758644683`, 0.026695295036220854`, 0.02434320166780811`, 0.022358942854932548`, 0.02066014280053327`, 0.019257806737695404`, 0.01778849788209615`, 0.01616702991772085`, 0.014664191285898848`, 0.013445992263960137`, 0.01192332859442535`, 0.01084525561840847`, 0.009801815405948468`, 0.008234873753195043`, 0.007054349584347242`, 0.005905954296891378`, 0.004856702736904681`, 0.003845110244127089`, 0.0037771945048303336`, 0.002935206313477711`, 0.002040321920311224`, 0.0014071787629923048`, 0.0009391281577906015`, 0.000805903695161852`, 0.0011210325676916917`, 0.0017256255939822219`, 0.0031838712868888916`, 0.0054595609893070855`, 0.007983379263671932`, 0.013820688700870066`, 0.021660425326538245`, 0.03302169545858874`, 0.04822265648372334`, 0.07099810670551317`, 0.10124931684134038`, 0.14191988704230168`}, {0.11247506279880036`, 0.12613898250207659`, 0.11412413693840996`, 0.0950137347462231`, 0.07369857648939358`, 0.060896582549578096`, 0.0529015649055831`, 0.047238928659755354`, 0.0423733242054878`, 0.03872519684290074`, 0.03412125821014748`, 0.03326601277881612`, 0.03109269217842166`, 0.029315351242750632`, 0.027748389152616203`, 0.02644715856500834`, 0.025316510032229664`, 0.024262882807963012`, 0.02293363965293731`, 0.022073000654977654`, 0.021037996277405865`, 0.020235479674301077`, 0.0195520434080593`, 0.018865577379461953`, 0.018164631829732894`, 0.017454797346545717`, 0.01634202464553459`, 0.015548840229664115`, 0.014655454177227266`, 0.013651374510481937`, 0.012282122366105257`, 0.011035776678649942`, 0.009885353679705024`, 0.008818825595065265`, 0.007638873435715432`, 0.00659490812867028`, 0.005489784907292323`, 0.004171286427669103`, 0.0030786270281314247`, 0.002129265287631467`, 0.0013927962183021866`, 0.0009994878625972383`, 0.0012139822377452165`, 0.0023002836600257434`, 0.004475269225968855`, 0.008278622800150053`, 0.0144144124167983`, 0.02349794581969828`, 0.03656375377106626`}, {0.0017398733214249152`, 0.0010536819052031385`, 0.0010661600774307446`, 0.0015326965755493582`, 0.0011365080409880778`, 0.00041543870065526733`, 0.0008925626480206796`, 0.00038090889990418026`, 0.0003260785483409644`, 0.000351390754775441`, 0.00044297388385977166`, 0.0004819584020289412`, 0.0004172011222035853`, 0.0003618450190738899`, 0.00036798893877009104`, 0.00034469760619766177`, 0.0003298756366515439`, 0.0003232655605523282`, 0.0002801415236193982`, 0.0002854445455688256`, 0.00026730929676116645`, 0.00018390870457760987`, 0.0001811760969997499`, 0.00017870486805264072`, 0.0001767897769609245`, 0.0001761896432839935`, 0.00020771765494114632`, 0.00020274043884910015`, 0.00009151000712363794`, 0.00009806252142065017`, 0.00008709351846784678`, 0.0000325811919917538`, 0.00011870916316730831`, 0.00010787318870987004`, 0.0002144402801841187`, 0.00009378576377482524`, 0.00003846478307662363`, 0.00002897077863667504`, 0.00002765158403978311`, 0.000025336414321146442`, 0.0000731702789576156`, 3.46757644244792`*^-7, 0.000015973019935465914`, 0.00001212311866537321`, 3.990983864573654`*^-6, 4.347347522404118`*^-6, 5.136807399349096`*^-6, 5.106093941015749`*^-6, 4.98405516501858`*^-6}, {9.227117119404563`*^-6, 0.0005716086847459465`, 0.00033801177118022015`, 0.0001516141263456208`, 0.00018404189433883787`, 0.00013548259171344845`, 0.00010259173976206371`, 0.00007374044192414684`, 0.000052334776241308574`, 0.000035294896896907246`, 0.00004872265108969646`, 8.860726853259576`*^-7, 4.726390435221727`*^-7, 5.724941340676175`*^-7, 3.4780065721131523`*^-9, 3.7903102813189985`*^-9, 5.9528234581666206`*^-9, 1.01684709315301`*^-7, 8.498413348241246`*^-8, 3.515305957394482`*^-9, 2.6952428407212133`*^-7, 1.8259401100117924`*^-6, 1.6701484529661894`*^-6, 3.308234166966656`*^-7, 3.642146045072711`*^-7, 3.5233819433016545`*^-7, 7.535309206730319`*^-6, 8.406813706288636`*^-6, 0.000011104825718486986`, 0.000010136237688580514`, 7.210520902219036`*^-6, 1.6724399419157887`*^-6, 2.180679910422483`*^-7, 2.9026679539025686`*^-7, 3.075946771185963`*^-6, 9.981264600841704`*^-7, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.00010407681141312184`, 0.00015459372985525912`, 0.00020865029939978166`, 0.0002796968114525878`}, {0.008704211251995525`, 0.008268222612229424`, 0.004770542211755052`, 0.00325181190736286`, 0.0020249438030327145`, 0.001869930429180984`, 0.0011005167620291706`, 0.0010201693397347002`, 0.0007799255861042038`, 0.0005905294961779399`, 0.0004815202423909694`, 0.00032870947786488633`, 0.0003042525551666925`, 0.0002827171623517484`, 0.00026049201374141173`, 0.00024635083352517265`, 0.0002334605163923643`, 0.00021621340653066816`, 0.00025229955643444663`, 0.00022913355647881603`, 0.00024089797599346702`, 0.0002449206249809397`, 0.00023494524227721418`, 0.00009455751853265325`, 0.00009484324028747201`, 0.00009541071992155595`, 0.00009039219136387816`, 0.00009745134972993474`, 0.00013057062633774658`, 0.0001317146064234443`, 0.00012658501376616195`, 0.00021634474062976326`, 0.00021979096513800715`, 0.00030084315594316877`, 0.00037359982865190036`, 0.0003763149467529264`, 0.00023900639728311252`, 0.0003777968060245703`, 0.000367506730301991`, 0.0003844999270567389`, 0.0004633225569996127`, 0.0005258343098948772`, 0.0006224672054171984`, 0.0007213389024448656`, 0.0007857122529732638`, 0.000858058710380073`, 0.0009385123147080414`, 0.0011085063666908695`, 0.0013268119917351111`}, {0.0014831218686355478`, 0.0007012527792262987`, 0.0003151264670751808`, 0.000021720529499829777`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.000043516835441092386`, 0.00004212319410551724`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.000039792837013976204`, 0.000043328575900166005`, 0.000049729978379470225`, 0.00005478286592172169`, 0.00004056490077312064`, 0.000030390038106872735`, 0.00006556827014420818`, 0.0000702562999990568`, 0.00008920296281940673`, 0.00002612344428889564`, 6.644782763183073`*^-6, 0.000011415785129092408`, 0.000044199629046771976`, 0.00006253108826643081`, 0.`, 0.00008817637091403732`, 0.00009705037179729824`, 0.0001021806435412865`, 0.00009821512372662405`, 0.00014497317909360505`, 0.00018106791802607926`, 0.00022894625793516026`}, {0.009322698981132036`, 0.006785244282203787`, 0.0045533036546891665`, 0.002902769911896563`, 0.0024390333377398475`, 0.0014723103736666336`, 0.0010777256088430008`, 0.0008371841067505788`, 0.0006960996836703479`, 0.0006267708208317803`, 0.0004606928998800141`, 0.0004978942093350993`, 0.0003938117709958195`, 0.0003234921053511163`, 0.0003053144385674765`, 0.0002610160012882409`, 0.00022524314401816133`, 0.00019070466012229096`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.00006071034969031326`, 0.000031730128697822774`, 0.00004625189964065783`, 0.00004539417338592192`, 0.00004398279078974961`, 0.000027977016710637726`, 0.000025916887582162753`, 0.000016452422732566875`, 0.000014646524353694852`, 5.462329840748853`*^-6, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.007143285262750429`, 0.008655361202462674`, 0.044369306834008235`, 0.08236856394845131`, 0.1188303312030699`, 0.1332050928982539`, 0.1467170695322194`, 0.15296461918495868`, 0.1594759682085553`, 0.1656275627469415`, 0.16798879258496519`, 0.16993176280684535`, 0.1703949276745289`, 0.17096796832003033`, 0.17177627749618457`, 0.17223425197848302`, 0.17246191306368447`, 0.1726757452790567`, 0.17129409951471541`, 0.1713699294899998`, 0.1695618464120315`, 0.1692844601915361`, 0.1690690341592238`, 0.16945464311487707`, 0.16899737861940933`, 0.1684552715824301`, 0.16712339867759263`, 0.16656212323564729`, 0.16530074054764254`, 0.1650730215039648`, 0.16529420216085058`, 0.16436232027094394`, 0.1656595855058706`, 0.16632366850482802`, 0.16513350025154697`, 0.16562687586993352`, 0.17072648247982905`, 0.17312445139107732`, 0.17694044632128839`, 0.18007012231870295`, 0.18370873552566944`, 0.19238471414618996`, 0.19933638302151624`, 0.20563092173655917`, 0.21332144703661474`, 0.22144249439579755`, 0.2325478996472318`, 0.24286290235339747`, 0.25299490611094944`}};
```

Then the whole data set is given by

```
Data = Table[DataT1/i, {i, 1, 5}];
```

and the function who plots the results

```
PrintChart[Time_, Data_] := 
Module[{BSC, AL}, 
BSC = Reverse[
ColorDataFunction["SunsetColors", "Gradients", {0, 1},Blend["SunsetColors", #] &] /@Subdivide[49]];
AL = {"", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(S\), \(T\)]\) [-]"}; 
BarChart[Data[[Time]], GridLines -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> AL, BarSpacing -> 0, ChartLabels -> {Placed[Table[StringForm["X``", i], {i, 1, 18}], Axis,Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &], None}, ChartStyle -> {Opacity[0.7], BSC}, ImageSize -> 250,PlotRange -> {All, {0, 0.55}}]]
```

Which evaluated at t=1 (`PrintChart[1, Data]`) gives the following result

[image: Result at Time t=1]

Now imagine that the above result represent some data at time t=1. I would like to create a 3d plot representing a time line from t=1 to t=5 by assembling multiple 2d barchart plots (given by `PrintChart[1, Data]`,`PrintChart[2, Data]`,`PrintChart[3, Data]`,...), so that the result looks like this image

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: How the days are defined in your data? What you show in the last plot is not comprised of 2d bar charts? It shows some points as a function of time (t) and day.

Comment: I will update my post for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an attempt. Usually, for all the 2D expressions that I want to embed in a 3D space I use [Texture](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Texture.html) which is then placed within an area defined by a [Polygon](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon.html). The Polygon can be defined in any dimension and shape that you want. Its shape is defined from the coordinates of its points and every line segment consists of two consecutive points. The dimension of its point automatically defines the dimensions of the polygon.

For your case:

```
f[x_] := DataT1/x;
nstep = 5;
allPL = Table[ListDensityPlot[f[i], Frame -> False, AspectRatio -> 1],{i, 1, nstep}];
```

Which has as a first element

```
allPL[[1]]
```

[image]

Now you express all these outputs as a 3D graphic:

```
all3D = Graphics3D[Table[{Opacity[0.9], Texture[Rotate[allPL[[i]], 90 Degree]], EdgeForm[],
Polygon[{{0, i*timeStep, 0}, {0, i*timeStep, 20}, {50, i*timeStep,20}, {50, i*timeStep, 0}}, 
VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]},{i, 1, nstep}], ImageSize -> 800, 
Lighting -> DirectionalLight[White, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 20, 0}}], 
AspectRatio -> 1.3, PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 130}, {0, 30}}, 
Axes -> True, Boxed -> False, AxesEdge -> {{0, 0}, {1, -1}, {0,0}}, 
Ticks -> {Automatic, Table[{i, i/20}, {i, 0, nstep*20, 20}], Automatic}, BaseStyle -> 18, 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "Time T", "y"}, ViewPoint -> {2.52, -2.167, 0.622}, ViewVertical -> {0.245, -0.073,0.9667}]
```

[image]